# How to get data from a specific cell by specifying data from another cell in the same row

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with columns *username*, *forename*, *lastname* etc.

[image: My table]

I want to find the forename/lastname by specifying the username. For example, if I had used **"Test123"** I would get **"Test"** and **"Test"**.

Comment: RTLM? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29

Comment: ok, it's bugging me and I can't figure it out: what's the "L" stand for?

Comment: @Tobi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've downvoted this question because we tend to expect people to explain what they've tried - we think it is much better in the long run for programmers to learn to be self-sufficient with a search engine and other sources of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT forename, lastname FROM `table` WHERE username = 'Test123'
```

Answer (score 0):

its good to use prepared statements and bind your variables to avoid SQL injection. If you are unfamiliar with it i suggest read up on it.

```
$query = 'SELECT lastname, forename FROM TestTable WHERE username = :uname';

//using PDO
$stmt = PDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':uname', $userName, DB::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
   echo $row['forename'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']; //prints: Test Test
}

$stmt->closeCursor();
```